# Can there be a conformal map $D\to D^*$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here, $D$ is the open unit disc in the plane $\mathbb{C}$ and $D^*=D\setminus\{0\}$.

I know $D^*$ can be mapped conformally onto $D$. Now, I want to know if there can be a surjective conformal map $D\to D^*$.

The definitions I'm using state $f$ is conformal if and only if $f$ is analytic and $f'(z)\neq 0$ for every $z$ in the domain of $f$.

If not, how can I show that? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: "Conformal" usually implies bijective. Do you mean this?

Comment: I suppose he means that a conformal map is one that is locally biholomorphic, but not globally.

Comment: @zhw. The definitions I'm using state that $f$ is conformal iff $f$ is analytic and $f'(z)\neq 0$ for every $z$ in the domain of $f$. Does this imply $f$ is bijective?

Comment: @TRmate no it doesn't, it's precisely what I stated.

Comment: Oh, ok. Didn't know what locally biholomorphic means. Btw I'll edit my first post.

Comment: No it doesn't. Just wanted to clear up what definition you're using.

Comment: Why not map $D$ to the left half plane, then compose with $e^z$? Btw how do you handle $D* \to D$?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you, @zhw. If I'm not wrong, $D^*\to D$ is almost the same. Send $D^*$ to the upper half plane and then to $e^{iz}$.

Comment: @TRmate Doesn't work, since $e^{iz}$ leaves out $0$.

Comment: Oh, of course...